# Kinect Visual Gesture Builder unable to build the gesture

Tags: kinect

I have created a project in VGB, to detect wave gesture, I have added a clip of wave gesture, Set the gesture value to true by selecting gesture from the stream. but when I click on build I receive following error. Please can some one tell me why this error occurs? and what should I do to eliminate it?[image]